# Why prefer wait/notify to while cycle?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have some misunderstanding with advantages of wait/notify. As i understand processor core will do nothing helpful in both cases so what's the reason tro write complex wait/notify block codes instead of just waiting in cycle? 
 I'm clear that wait/notify will not steal processor time in case when two threads are executed on only one core.

Comment: Im guessing that in waiting in cycle as you suggest you are constantly checking whether the thing you are waiting for has finished, which is wasteful and if you use sleeps you are just guessing with timing, whereas with wait/notify you sit idle until the process that you are waiting on _tells you_ it is finished. Also as things get more complex the while loop starts to fall apart in both complexity and extensibility

Comment: @the_kaba I think you answered your question almost by saying `I'm clear that wait/notify will not steal processor time in case`. Only thing I would add is **this true irrespective of one core or multi-core**. `wait/notify` wont keep the cpu in a busy-wait situation compared to `while(true)` cycle.

Comment: I mean what's the reason not to run core but wait? There's no helpful work in any case and you're unable to use core when it's in waiting state. Is it just about increasing lifetime of processor hardware?

Comment: @the_kaba if you use wait/notify, another thread/process can use the processor - if you busy wait (while) it's not the case.

Comment: @the_kaba I think you are looking at it from a single application perspective where there is only one application with one thread is running. Think of it from a real world application (like web/app servers or standalone) where there are many threads running and competing for cpu cycles - you can see the advantage of `wait/notify`. You would definitely not want even a single thread to just do a busy-wait and burn the cpu cycles.

Comment: should (any of) you actually write an answer about it?

Comment: @the_kaba Just want to add, even if it a single application thread running on your system there are always OS running and its related processes that are competing for CPU cycles. You don't want them to starve them because of the application doing a `while busy-wait`

Comment: Also, a CPU that is is busy-waiting uses _much_ more power than a CPU that is in a paused state, waiting only for interrupts.  That is important in battery-powered applications.  A smart-phone app that busy-waits can greatly impact the battery life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Waiting in a cycle" is most commonly referred to as a "**busy loop**" or "**busy wait**":

```
 while ( ! condition()) {
     // do nothing
 }
 workThatDependsOnConditionBeingTrue();
```

This is very disrespectful of other threads or processes that may need CPU time (it takes 100% time from that core if it can). So there is another variant:

```
 while ( ! condition()) {
     sleepForShortInterval();
     // do nothing
 }
 workThatDependsOnConditionBeingTrue();
```

The small sleep in this variant will drop CPU usage dramatically, even if it is ~100ms long, which should not be noticeable unless your application is real-time.

Note that there will generally be a delay between when the condition actually becomes true and when `sleepForShortInterval()` ends. If, to be more polite to others, you sleep longer -- the delay will increase. This is generally unacceptable in real-time scenarios.

The nice way to do this, assuming that whatever `condition()` is checking is being changed from another thread, is to have the other thread wake you up when it finishes whatever you are waiting for. Cleaner code, no wasted CPU, and no delays.

Of course, it's quicker to implement a busy wait, and it may justified for quick'n'dirty situations.

Beware that, in a multithreaded scenario where `condition()` can be changed to false as well as true, you will need to protect your code between the `while` and the `workThatDependsOnConditionBeingTrue()` to avoid other threads changing its value in this precise point of time (this is called a *race codition*, and is very hard to debug after the fact).

Comment: Thanks for quick answer! By the way, i've read some books about concurrency few weeks ago and now need some practice. You look like a pro, could you advice some tasks which i may try to solve?

Comment: Good exercises depend very heavily on your programming level. A long time ago, I had some fun with [robocode](http://robocode.sourceforge.net/) - try to write yourself a [multithreaded bot](http://robocode.sourceforge.net/)!

Comment: Re, "...unless your application is real-time."  There is no particular time-scale that defines "real-time."  An application is "real-time" if it has outputs that are required to appear within specific time windows.  A window could be minutes wide (e.g., a house thermostat), or it could be microseconds wide (e.g., software-defined radio applications) or it could be anything in-between.

Comment: @jameslarge - while incorrect, it is common usage to use the term _real time_ to refer to _must not be delayed_. From context, up to 100ms delays. I feel that in this case there is no potential for confusion.

Comment: How is "must not be delayed" incorrect?  It's just another way of saying part of what I said.  For certain outputs of a real-time system, there's a window of correctness.  If the output is delayed (i.e., if it does not occur until after the window has closed), then the output is not correct.  But what does "delayed" mean?  In my example of a house thermostat, a delay of five minutes might go unnoticed by the homeowner.  But if we're directly controlling the ignition in an automobile engine, a delay of a hundred microseconds might be unacceptable.

Comment: I agree that your definition of _real time_ is perfectly correct; my usage of _real time_ is only in the second, popular but not-strictly-correct, sense of _must not be delayed_. However, to keep the answer short and not insert long definitions, I have preferred to use this somewhat-incorrect version instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think you answered your question almost by saying

> I'm clear that wait/notify will not steal processor time in case.

Only thing I would add is, this true irrespective of one core or multi-core. `wait/notify` wont keep the cpu in a busy-wait situation compared to `while` loop or periodic check.

> what's the reason not to run core but wait? There's no helpful work in any case and you're unable to use core when it's in waiting state.

I think you are looking at it from a single application perspective where there is only one application with one thread is running. Think of it from a real world application (like web/app servers or standalone) where there are `many threads` running and `competing for cpu cycles` - you can `see the advantage of wait/notify.` You would definitely not want even a single thread to just do a busy-wait and burn the cpu cycles.

Even if it a single application/thread running on the system there are always OS process running and its related processes that keep competing for the CPU cycles. You don't want them to starve them because the application is doing a `while busy-wait`.

Quoting from Gordon's comment

> waiting in cycle as you suggest you are constantly checking whether the thing you are waiting for has finished, which is wasteful and if you use sleeps you are just guessing with timing, whereas with wait/notify you sit idle until the process that you are waiting on tells you it is finished.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. I just missed something about thread states. Here's description from oracle documents:
WAITING
A thread that is waiting indefinitely for another thread to perform a particular action is in this state.

 Does it means that resources which thread used before waiting are free and they may be used by another threads/processes? In this case how we can be sure that code will be executed right after notification? Is there any extra priority for this cases?

Comment: @the_kaba **Does it .. resources which thread .. waiting..** - if you are referring `resources` as the object on which the the thread has called the `wait` method, yes it is true and now some other thread can acquire lock on the same object. But if you are referring to the OS resources like `file`,etc opened by this thread, they are not released and are held by waiting thread. **How .. sure that code ..  executed..** - we cannot guarantee that because once notify is called the scheduler will pick up one of the threads waiting for that lock. Unless this is the only thread waiting for this lock.

Answer (score 1):

In general, your application is not the only one running on the CPU. Using non-spinning waiting is, first of all, an act of courtesy towards the other processes/threads which are competing for the CPU in order to do some useful job. The CPU scheduler cannot know a-priori if your thread is going to do something useful or just spin on a false flag. So, it can't tune itself based on that, unless you tell it you don't want to be run, because there's nothing for you to do.

Indeed, busy-waiting is faster than getting the thread to sleep, and that's why usually the wait() method is implemented in a hybrid way. It first spins for a while, and then it actually goes to sleep.

Besides, it's not just waiting in a loop. You still need to synchronize access to the resources you're spinning on. Otherwise, you'll fall victim of race conditions.

If you feel the need of a simpler interface, you might also consider using `CyclicBarrier`, `CountDownLatch` or a `SynchronousQueue`.